# See how much `file.read` read in Python 3

Tags: python, file

> Read and return up to size bytes. If the argument is omitted, None, or
>   negative, data is read and returned until EOF is reached. An empty
>   bytes object is returned if the stream is already at EOF.
>
> If the argument is positive, and the underlying raw stream is not
>   interactive, multiple raw reads may be issued to satisfy the byte
>   count (unless EOF is reached first). But for interactive raw streams,
>   at most one raw read will be issued, **and a short result does not imply
>   that EOF is imminent.**
>
> A BlockingIOError is raised if the underlying raw stream is in non
>   blocking-mode, and has no data available at the moment.
>
> **[io.BufferedIOBase.read](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase.read)**

If a result returned by a read operation can have its length be less than the given or expected amount; and still not suggest that the EOF has been reached, what reliable way of chunking would be most reliable?

```
import os
import io

def reliable_read(file_obj, amount=None, chk_size=2):
    file_size = os.fstat(file_obj.file_no()).st_size
    data = b"" if isinstance(file_obj, io.BufferedReader) else ""
    amount_read = 0

    if amount is None:
        amount = file_size
    while amount_read < amount:
       data += file_obj.read(chk_size)
    return data
```

Initially I thought that for some reason, the lower the chunk-size the higher the probability that the read will execute fully; however I don't exactly know whether this is true- therefore it tests the reliability of the above function.
It's quite inefficient too, as the `chk_size` approaches 1 the amount of function calls approaches the `file_size` which isn't optimal for really big files.

Essentially, without using the CFFI to import `fopen`, `fread` and `fclose`- what builtin function or library exists which allows for a reliable read, also within the essence of my title; a function that returns the exact amount read, either placing the read buffer into a list by reference, or as a tuple of `(data, n_read)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note in the documentation you quoted:

> multiple **raw** reads may be issued to satisfy the byte count

Which means that this loop is useless. The raw read is the read performed by the OS, using `read()`, which can return less than requested on some input streams.

```
while amount_read < amount:
   data += file_obj.read(chk_size)
```

(plus the loop isn't updating `amount_read` so I suspect that it has a bug)

Since you're using python file interface (not `os.read`), python is going to do that internally, with possible errors in the process, if one or many of the internal raw read required to complete the operation fails.

You don't control the inside `read`, so you just need to do:

```
data = file_obj.read(amount)
```

If you *don't* want to use pyhton interface, then go for `os.read` with full controls and raw error checking that you'll have to manage.